# Can we execute sql query in aws DMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-dms, aws-glue-data-catalog

Can we execute sql query inside DMS task so that it just fetches the required data and not the whole db.
If its not possible then which aws service is used to fetch query based data from on-prem data source to aws S3.

Comment: What is your data source tech?

Answer (score 1):

You can use filters and/or exclude fields: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.html

Contact me if you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

For alternate solution to DMS, you can use AWS Glue with data retrieved using PYSPARK dataframe from on prem DB to either s3 and AWS RDS. This works very well. The only down side is the cost.

This solution supports both table and SQL as input for data extraction